# Comparing two array lists

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following array lists

```
List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
List<Long> empIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

Now I need to compare these 2 arrays and check if any value in ids is there in empIds. If yes I need to exit with a boolean true. I have done this in the following way.

```
for (Long id : ids) {
    if (empIds.contains(id)) {
        checker = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

But this takes a lot of time. Can anybody please help me to optimize this?

Comment: What is the size of the arrays? and please share some time output.
I dont think there is a simpler way

Comment: Are either ids or empIds sorted or almost sorted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put `empIds` in a `HashSet` to improve the search time :

```
Set<Long> empIdsSet = new HashSet<Long>(empIds);
for (Long id : ids) {
    if (empIdsSet.contains(id)) {
        checker = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Each call to `empIdsSet.contains(id)` would take expected constant time (`O(1)`), which is better than the linear time required by each call to `empIds.contains(id)`.

Comment: This would assume that the time needed to hash the list does not matter.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The time to hash the list is linear, so the overall time is still better than the original code.

Comment: Too bad this got marked as a duplicate. This solution performs much faster than `Collections.disjoint` (which probably runs in quadratic time - similar to the OP's code)